# User defined function does work when passing variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The Camel scalar-valued function does not work when using variables

```
declare @primary_supervisor_name varchar(2000)
declare @lastname varchar(2000)
declare @containComma int
declare @position int
declare @result varchar(200)
DECLARE ts_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select primary_supervisor_name from Test
OPEN ts_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM ts_cursor INTO  @primary_supervisor_name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN                      
    set @containComma = CHARINDEX(',', @primary_supervisor_name)
    Begin
    IF (@containComma = 0)                                       
        set @position = CHARINDEX(' ' , @primary_supervisor_name)
        set @lastName = substring(@primary_supervisor_name, @position + 1, len(@primary_supervisor_name))
        set @lastName = LOWER(@lastName)
        print  dbo.CamelCase('test')  -- WORKS and PRINTs "Test"
        print  dbo.CamelCase(@lastName) -- does not do anything..no seeing any print output in console.
    end
    FETCH NEXT FROM ts_cursor INTO @primary_supervisor_name   
END
CLOSE ts_cursor
DEALLOCATE ts_cursor
```

The camel function does not work for `@lastName`.
Using the Camel function from https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/function-returns-string-in-proper-case-camelcase

Comment: The function in the example uses CamelCase as the function name. Are you calling it correctly. It appears to be proper sql. What does "---DOES NOT WORK" mean above?

Comment: What we need is a [mre] with the emphasis on minimal, including sample data. And letting us know the exact value of `@lastname` when calling the function. That will narrow down whether the issue is your code of the function code.

Comment: You need to add `print(@lastName)` to be sure you are passing the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be your program structure. Your BEGIN and END seem odd and off a bit.

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN                      
    set @containComma = CHARINDEX(',', @primary_supervisor_name)
    Begin
    ...
    IF (@containComma = 0)   
    end
    FETCH NEXT FROM ts_cursor INTO @primary_supervisor_name   
END
```

I would think you were going for the code block below

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN                      
    set @containComma = CHARINDEX(',', @primary_supervisor_name)
    IF (@containComma = 0) BEGIN  -- <--- Begin on this line?
    ...
    end
    FETCH NEXT FROM ts_cursor INTO @primary_supervisor_name   
END
```

Comment: thank you Ross for your solution. The Begin needed inside If. It works now. Thank you again.

Comment: no problem, glad I could help.